# Best way to decode encoding with byte shifts

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

My question is about how to retrieve the original string if information might have been lost in the process.
I'm reviewing an encoding routine that uses byte shifts in something like this:

```
def encode(string):
    encoded = ''
    for char in string:
        encoded += chr(ord(char) ^ (ord(char) >> 1))
    return encoded
```

With one bit if being shifted right I'm loosing information in certain cases, but I'm trying to figure out a way to reconstruct the original string in a way such that

```
def decode(string):
    decoded = ''
    for char in string:
        decoded += ........
    return decoded
```

As I'm loosing information for a list of given chars:

```
In [90]: ord('A') >> 1 << 1
Out[90]: 64

In [91]: ord('B') >> 1 << 1
Out[91]: 66

In [92]: ord('C') >> 1 << 1
Out[92]: 66
```

Would it be possible to reverse the encoded string? I've been bugging my head for a while and I have a sense that this can be done, but my brain seems to be stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael's answer proved that it's possible, and here's a trivial and probably fast way to do it, using a reverse lookup-table (just doing ASCII here):

```
def decode(string):
    return string.translate({i ^ i>>1: i for i in range(128)})
```

Demo:

```
>>> encode('StackOverflow')
'zNQR^hMWKUZXL'
>>> decode(encode('StackOverflow'))
'StackOverflow'
```

And a trivial experimental proof that it works:

```
>>> len({i ^ i>>1 for i in range(128)})
128
```

The 128 possible inputs lead to 128 different outputs, so no two different characters are encoded as the same character, so it's possible to reverse the process.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the highest order bit. It isn't XORed or otherwise modified. So you know it. The second highest order bit is XORed with the highest order one which you know already.

So you can undo this XOR and have the second highest bit, too. Repeat this until all bits are revealed. Also the information of the least significant bit is not lost here. It is only XORed with the second LSB.

I don't know if it's the most efficient way but I would XOR the encoded byte (let's name it `eb`) with `eb >> 1`.

The result is

`eb2 = eb ^ eb >> 1 # == char ^ char >> 2` (meaning `char` as byte value here)

then

```
eb3 = eb2 ^ eb2 >> 2 # == char ^ char >> 4
eb4 = eb3 ^ eb3 >> 4 # == char ^ char >> 8
```

For a byte `char >> 8 == 0` therefore `eb4 == char`.

Comment: Nice. I came up with the same method, but your reasoning is much better. I suspect the method is the best we can do for single-char decoding, disappointing that it's much more laborious than encoding. I guess it's easier to break something than to repair it :-). For longer strings I think it would be better to just use a lookup-table like I just posted.